# Xib doesn't save properly with autoresizing mask

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xib, autoresizingmask

I want to have a custom *UITableViewCell* that support all orientation.

I created *UITableViewCell* with xib file and put *UILabel* to the centre of my cell with flexible width and height attribute. Label has an orange background.

Label's autoresizing masks are shown on screenshot:

[image]

And my cell looks like

[image]

I didn't added any line of code. I just save and restarted xCode.
Now my cell looks like 
[image]

Every time I restarted xCode my label's width increase by 272 px and height by 46 px. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try to remove xib and create new one. Or open xib as XML file and find there height value, maybe issue is there... Looks like Xcode bug...

Comment: I've just created a new xib. The values are valid when I quitted xCode. But values are changed when I restarted xCode and opened xib file. May be it is an xCode bug.

Comment: Yes, of course. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55328092/View.xib

Comment: Looks like Xcode issue, same issue for me, also when I put another cell

Comment: I've just opened Xcode bug as 19351140. I will informed you when dev's respond to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that unchecking flexible width and height of the label  (the red cross in your first picture) would fix the problem. I think it has something to do with that its superview doesn't has flexible width and height.